# List all NuGet packages with Id, Version, License URL and Project URL

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I would like to extract the following information out of all installed nuget packages in my solution:
Id, Version, License URL and Project URL. The nuget package manager lists all of the informations I need for each package. (see picture)

[image: nuget package manager]

When I take a look at all the informations stored in each object in the nuget package manager console with the command `Get-Package | select *` I get the following exemplary result:

- ProjectName       : WebSchnittstellen
- Id                : Antlr
- Versions          : {3.5.0.2}
- AsyncLazyVersions : NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion[]
- Version           : 3.5.0.2
- AllVersions       : False
- LicenseUrl        : http://www.antlr3.org/license.html

By using `Get-Package | select -Unique Id, Version, LicenseUrl` I can extract one part of the needed information. But how can I add the Project URL to each entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible. And there is no parameter for `ProjectUrl` under `Get-Package | select xxx` command. And that is a feature request.

So if you want that, you should [request a feature to the Team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion) and when you finish that, you could share the link here and anyone who is interested in it including us will vote it. And those will help get more attention from **Microsoft**.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the [Nuget License Utility](https://github.com/tomchavakis/nuget-license) CLI tool

First, install the tool:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-project-licenses
```

Then run the tool to display a table with the licensing information (use the -i flag to indicate the solution/project directory to run against, this example assumes the current directory)

```
dotnet-project-licenses -i .
```